# How to delete a folder in /usr/bin?

Tags: uninstall, delete, adobe-reader

I tried to install Adobe Reader 9.bin. In Terminal, I did set the path to `/usr/bin`. Now I cannot delete this app because it does not work correctly. Please help me out. Thanks in advance. My Ubuntu is 13.04.

Comment: How did you install Adobe Reader 9, exactly? Where did you download it? What file did you download? (Can you include a link?) Exactly what commands did you run, or what actions did you perform, to install it? What instructions, if any, did you use to install it? (Can you include a link to them, too?) Please **edit your question** to provide this information. That should make it possible for this question to be answered.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *I cannot delete this app because it does not work correctly.*? You can't delete it because it is not working properly? That doesn't make too much sense. How did you try deleting the folder? What instructions you followed? Please edit your question and add the additional info.

Answer (score 5):

Apart from using nautilus you can simply delete the folder directly from the command line.

if for example the folder your trying to delete is */usr/bin/adobe* then you would need to type:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/adobe
```

Obviously, make sure you typed in the correct folder before executing the command.

Answer (score 2):

To delete a folder as root, you must do the following:
- Be sure to have Nautilus installed
- in terminal type gksu nautilus and enter your root password
- The Nautilus file browser window will open and the you should locate the desired folder (the one you wish to delete)
- Once you locate the folder you wish to delete, click on it and press Shift+Del
- Job done!
- Close terminal and Nautilus will automaticaly shut down.